# Какие бывают библиотеки для управления мышкой и клавиотурой python

Tags: python-3.x

Какие нужны библиотеки для языка python

Answer (score 1):

Один из лучших - PyAutoGUI. Сам им пользуюсь, функционал велик. Рекомендую)

Answer (score 1):

[PyAutoGUI](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/), если вам нужно всё вместе,
[Keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) и [Mouse](https://pypi.org/project/mouse/), если по отдельности.
Я считаю, их вполне достаточно.